# Reading from stdin (file of variable length)

Tags: c, stdin

So I've been trying to get this to assignment work in various different ways, but each time I get different errors. Basically what we have is a program that needs to read, byte by byte, the contents of a file that will be piped in (the file length could be humongous so we can't just call malloc and allocated a large chunk of space). We are required to use realloc to expand the amount of freed memory until we reach the end of the file. The final result should be one long C string (array) containing each byte (and we can't disregard null bytes either if they are part of the file). What I have at the moment is:

```
   char *buff;
   int n = 0;
   char c;
   int count;

   if (ferror (stdin))
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "error reading file\n");
      exit (1);
   }
   else
   {
      do {   
         buff = (char*) realloc (buff, n+1);
         c = fgetc (stdin);
         buff[n] = c;
         if (c != EOF)
             n++;
     }
       while (c != EOF);
   }
   printf("characters entered: ");
   for (count = 0; count < n; count++)
       printf("%s ", buff[count]);
   free (buff);
```

It should keep reading until the end of the file, expanding the memory each time but when I try to run it by piping in a simple text file, it tells me I have a segmentation fault. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

Note that we're allowed to use malloc and whatnot, but I couldn't see how to make that work since we have know idea how much memory is needed.

Answer (score 3):

You are using an unassigned pointer buf in your first call to realloc. Change to

```
char *buf = malloc(100);
```

to avoid this problem.

Once you get it working, you'll notice that your program is rather inefficient, with a realloc per character. Consider realloc-ing in larger chunks to reduce the number of reallocations.

Answer (score 3):

```
char* buff;
...
buff = (char*) realloc (buff, n+1);
```

You're trying to reallocate an unitialized pointer, which leads to undefined behaviour. Change to

```
char* buff = 0;
...
buff = (char*) realloc (buff, n+1);
```

But as has been pointed out, this is very inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the answers by @dasblinkenlight and @smocking are the current reason, but to avoid the next crashes:

1. Change `char c;` to `int c;`, as the EOF is represented by more than one char.
2. This is a bad idea to call realloc for one char at a time, instead increase the size in X bytes (let's say 100) each time, this will be MUCH more efficient.
3. You need to add the null terminator ('\0') at the end of the buffer, otherwise - undefined behavior at `printf()`.

Comment: Ah, whoops. I forgot about that. That seems to have fixed it along with setting char *buff to NULL. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with for reading `stdin` into a `char[]` or `char*` (when having embedded `NULL`s in `stdin`):

```
char* content = NULL;
char c;
int contentSize = 0;

while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF){
    contentSize++;
    content = (char*)(realloc(content, contentSize+1));
    if (content == NULL) {
        perror("Realloc failed.");
        exit(2);
    }
    content[contentSize] = c;
}

for (int i = 0; i < contentSize; ++i) {
    printf("%c",content[i]);
}
```